# I cant figure out how to unplug the temperature sensor on my 2006 KIA RIO

Tags: sensor

What is the trick to unplug the temperature sensors on a 2006 KIA RIO

Answer (score 1):

[image]

To get it off, push the connector in towards the sensor. While keeping pressure on it, press the catch (green arrow). Then, while continuing to press the catch, pull the connector off of the sensor. The little thumb doohicky pivots in the middle. If it still doesn't want to release, put a small flat tip screwdriver between the sensor and the connector, prying up just slightly so the doohicky will clear the tab on the sensor (below).

[image]